# Function to table an array

Tags: javascript

I was recently asked an interview question to tableify an given array. For example given the following input

```
var list = ['Adam', 'Brad', 'Cari', 'Donna', 'Ethan', 'Fred', 'Grok', 'Han', 'Izzy', 'Jay'];
var columns = 3;  // 2 or 4...., etc
```

The output should look as following

```
// [
//  [ 'Adam', 'Ethan', 'Izzy'],
//  [ 'Brad', 'Fred', 'Jay'], 
//  [ 'Cari', 'Grok'],
//  [ 'Donna', 'Han']
   ]
```

The following function was provided to me and I had to implement the logic

```
function tableify (list, columns) {

 var result = [];
 return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify( tableify(list, columns)));
```

I was able to get through the problem half way, where given the **columns** input you would divide with the length of the array and use it to push the values in children array

For example, if the columns value is '2' the output would look like the following

```
  [

  ['Adam', 'Fred']
  ['Brad', 'Grok']  
  ['Cari','Han']
  ['Donna','Izzy']
  ['Ethan','Jay']

  ]
```

I am struggling to lay down the underlying logic

Edit:

This was my attempt at it

```
function tableify (list, columns) {

 var result = [];

    var rows = Math.ceil(list.length/ columns);
    var removed = list.splice(rows, list.length -1);
    //console.log(rows);
    //console.log(removed);
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        result.push([list[i]]);
    }

    var j = 0;
    var join = result.map(function(elements){
        console.log(elements);
        elements.push(removed[j])
        j++;
    });


    return result;
}
```

My thought process was to have two different arrays, one with all the items in the first column in ['Adam', 'Brad', 'Cari', 'Donna'] and rest of the items in the **"removed"** array.

After performing the splice, i wanted to push the remaining items from the original array into **"results"**, and then call the mapping method to push the elements from the **"removed"** array into **results**.

But the issue here is it will only map elements into the second column and skip the elements for the third column

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Hint, consider using `.splice()` or `.slice()` to grab N unit segments from the original array.

Comment: In words, you want to take `columns` items in the array, `while` there is at least one remaining. Translate that in javascript and you get it to work. Interviewers usually don't mind if you get the logic but are unfamiliar with the keywords to use. Easy enough to learn keywords so I'd go with the logic first, and if you struggle to find the exact syntax in the langage they will be glad to help with that without too much penalty.

Comment: It seems they want rows to be missing at most one cell, so you can mod the total by the number of columns to get the remainder, then that many rows at the bottom should have just the last cell empty. E.g. for 10 items in 3 columns, `10%3` is 2, so the last two rows have 3-1 (i.e. 2) cells.

Comment: Define rows, inside function, too. Rows should be: list.length/columns. Round it using Math.ceil() - it seems that that's a rule in your case (in your example output -> just first two rows have 3 columns)... Then you can make two loops... Btw, not bad question at all, it didn't deserved so many down-votes...shame that OP didn't posted what he tried...

Comment: Hi thank you for the feedback, i have added to the OP of my attempt and thought process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time i dev. a algorithm for this case. Here it is:

```
function tableify (list, columns) {
    var countUsed = 0;
    var len = list.length;
    var maxRow = Math.ceil(len / columns);
    var result = [];
    for(i = 0; countUsed < len; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < maxRow && countUsed < len; j++){
            //check if the sub array is initialized
            if(!result[j]){
                result[j] = [];
            }
            result[j][i] = list[countUsed];
            countUsed++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}   

//output test
var list = ["Adam", "Brad", "Cari", "Donna", "Ethan", "Fred", "Grok", "Han", "Izzy", "Jay"];
var columns = 3;
var a = tableify(list, columns);
document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
```

The output will be like you want:

```
[
 [ 'Adam', 'Ethan', 'Izzy'],
 [ 'Brad', 'Fred', 'Jay'], 
 [ 'Cari', 'Grok'],
 [ 'Donna', 'Han']
]
```

I tested in many other cases and it works.

Comment: "I don't know why i can't acess the length of the array inside the function" - var len = list.length; - not 'lenght' , you had small typo...

Comment: Np, i hope OP got the job. :)

Comment: @SamuelGiordano thnxs, i don't know why i didn't  think of it in this way result[j][i] = list[countUsed];

Comment: NP @RajPowar we're here to help